# How to set connection string in excel to import data from sql?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to import data from 2 columns in SQL server, im following this code from http://buffalobi.com/excel/excel-vba-import-sql-server-data/, whats wrong?

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Call CommandButton1_Click

    Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection, cmd As New ADODB.Command, rs As New ADODB.Recordset

    With conn
        .ConnectionString = _
            "Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; " & _
            "data source=localhost; " & _
            "initial catalog=PTrails_Core_DB;" & _
            "integrated security=True;"
        .Open
    End With
```

and i get this message 
[image: ERROR-MSG]

Answer (score 0):

I would set 'ConnectionString' as variable and use that to open. If this doesn't work, it would have to be the actual link you're referring to that's causing an issue. Maybe because it's ending on semicolon.

```
Dim ConnectionString as String

ConnectionString = "Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;data source=localhost;initial catalog=PTrails_Core_DB;integrated security=True"

conn.Open ConnectionString
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you want.

```
Sub ImportFromSQLServer()

Dim Cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim Server_Name As String
Dim Database_Name As String
Dim User_ID As String
Dim Password As String
Dim SQLStr As String
Dim RS As ADODB.Recordset
Set RS = New ADODB.Recordset

Server_Name = "your_server_name"
Database_Name = "Northwind"
'User_ID = "******"
'Password = "****"

SQLStr = "select Field1, Field2 from dbo.TBL" 'and PostingDate = '2006-06-08'"

Set Cn = New ADODB.Connection
Cn.Open "Driver={SQL Server};Server=" & Server_Name & ";Database=" & Database_Name & ";"
'& ";Uid=" & User_ID & ";Pwd=" & Password & ";"

RS.Open SQLStr, Cn, adOpenStatic

    With Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
        .ClearContents
        .CopyFromRecordset RS
    End With

RS.Close
Set RS = Nothing
Cn.Close
Set Cn = Nothing

End Sub
```